# Задача на количество ревью отелей

Tags: java, алгоритм

Есть задача которая не решается, точнее все верно решается, но в нескольких тесткейсах есть таймаут, на Java 7.

> Given a set of hotels and its guests reviews, sort the hotels based on a list of words specified by a user. The criteria to sort the hotels should be how many times the words specified by the user is mentioned in the hotel reviews.
>
> **Input**:
>
> The first line contains a space-separated set of words which we want to find mentions in the hotel reviews.
>
> The second line contains one integer M, which is the number of reviews.
>
> This is followed by M+M lines, which alternates an hotel ID and a review belonging to that hotel.
>
> **Output**
>
> A list of hotel IDs sorted, in descending order, by how many mentions they have of the words specified in the input.
>
> **Notes**
>
> – The words to be find will always be singe words line ‘breakfast’ or ‘noise’. Never double words like ‘swimming pool’.
>
> – Hotel ud is a 4-byte integer.
>
> – Words match should be case-insensitive.
>
> – Dots and commas should be ignored.
>
> – If a word appears in a review twice, it should count twice.
>
> – If two hotels have the same number of mentions, they should be sorted in the output based on their ID, smallest ID first.
>
> – In case one or more test cases time out, consider revisiting the runtime complexity of your algorithms.
>
> **Sample output**
>
> 2 1
>
> 1
>
> 2 1

Решение вроде как самое быстрое, как можно еще улучшить?

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
    System.setIn(new FileInputStream(System.getProperty("user.home") + "/in.txt"));
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String lookWords = scanner.nextLine();
    Set<String> lookWordsMap = new HashSet<>();
    for (String s : lookWords.split(" ")) {
        lookWordsMap.add(s.toLowerCase());
    }

    int countReviews = scanner.nextInt();
    Map<Integer, Integer> rate = new HashMap<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < countReviews; i++) {
        int hotelId = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine();
        String review = scanner.nextLine();
        if (!rate.containsKey(hotelId)) {
            rate.put(hotelId, 0);
        }
        for (String s : review.split(" ")) {
            s = s.replaceAll("[,.]", "").toLowerCase();
            if (lookWordsMap.contains(s)) {
                rate.put(hotelId, rate.get(hotelId) + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    List<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>> sortedList = new ArrayList(rate.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(sortedList, new Comparator<Map.Entry<Integer, Integer>>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> o1, Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> o2) {
            if (o1.getValue() > o2.getValue()) {
                return -1;
            } else if (o1.getValue() < o2.getValue()) {
                return 1;
            } else {
                if (o1.getKey() > o2.getKey()) {
                    return -1;
                } else if (o1.getValue() < o2.getValue()) {
                    return 1;
                }
            }
            return 0;
        }
        /*if (o1.getValue() == o2.getValue()) {
            return o1.getKey() - o2.getKey();
        } else {
            return o2.getValue() - o1.getValue();
        }*/
    });

    for (Map.Entry<Integer, Integer> integerIntegerEntry : sortedList) {
        System.out.print(integerIntegerEntry.getKey() + " ");
    }
}
```

Comment: Возможно в 7й версии джавы просто нет некоторых функций, из за чего и не проходит тесты?

Comment: Предпологается что должно проходить на любом языке, они даже написали в условиях In case one or more test cases time out, consider revisiting the runtime complexity of your algorithms.

Comment: У вас ошибка в компараторе, два раза проверяете `o1.getValue() < o2.getValue()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно убрать вложенный цикл по всем словам review и применить алгоритм Ахо-Корасик для поиска набора подстрок в строке.

Comment: На эту задачу дается 20 минут, я даже без ахо корасик потратил уйму времени и то не смог, а устраивался не алгоритмистом а просто разработчиком)

Comment: Это фейсбук? Интернетом пользоваться было нельзя?

Comment: Я наверное все 20 минут потратил чтобы просто въехать в задачу :-).

Comment: @ei-grad Что порекомендуете почитать?